# Xampp does not load page that is inside subfolder of Codeigniter view

Tags: php, macos, codeigniter, xampp

I have CodeIgniter Project on MAC and XAMPP and my views are inside some folders such as  `->View/layout/header.php` and I load it in controller as `$this->load->view('layout/header.php');` but upon running the project in browser it says unable to load specified page. (When I put my page in view directory It Works but I have many pages therefore it is difficult to shift all pages in view directory.) Any solution plz.? thanx in advance

Comment: i would just move all the views in to the correct folder. i'm not sure how it would be difficult as if this is a Ci project, all the views should be in the folder anyways

Comment: thankx Alex my all views are inside view such as view/myfolder/view.php

Comment: my view are not outside the view they are in view but in subfolder. It work fine in wamp and windows but not in xampp it say unable to load page myfolder/mypage.php

Comment: so long as all the views are in the `views` folder, even if they are in subfolders within that it should work fine. `$this->load->view('layout/header.php');` would be looking for a file in `views/layout/header.php` ... on some os's this is case sensitive. i'm not sure what your issue is then. if you can, post a screenshot of your directory tree for the file in question.

Comment: thanks @Alex it was the issue of case sensitiveness.